# Verificar se posição está entre 2 posições

Tags: java, hashmap

Estou usando esse código aqui para verificar se uma posição está 'dentro' de uma 'área', mas provavelmente isso vai explodir se a hashmap tiver muitas Keys/Values, qual seria a melhor maneira de fazer isso ? Obrigado.

```
HashMap<String, Region_> regionsHash = new HashMap<String, Region_>();
public class Region_ {
    public Region_ (vector _minPos, vector _maxPos){
        minPos = _minPos;
        maxPos = _maxPos;
    }

    vector minPos;
    vector maxPos;
}

class vector{
    vector (int _X, int _Y,int _Z){
        X = _X;
        Y = _Y;
        Z = _Z;
    }
    int X, Y, Z;
}

String getRegion (vector _vector3D){
    for (String regionKey : regionsHash.keySet()) {
        Region_ region = regionsHash.get(regionKey);

        if(region.maxPos.X >= _vector3D.X && region.maxPos.Y >= _vector3D.Y && region.maxPos.Z >= _vector3D.Z){
            if(region.minPos.X <= _vector3D.X && region.minPos.Y <= _vector3D.Y && region.minPos.Z <= _vector3D.Z){
                return regionKey;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode implementar o `equals` e o `hashcode` a partir das posições `x` e `y` no teu objeto `Region_`.

Altere o teu `HashMap` chave de String para `HashMap` chave de `Integer`, na chave do `hashmap` utilize o `hashcode` do teu objeto `Region`_, no método `getRegion` você pode fazer uma busca diretamente pelo hash, não é necessário realizar um `for` caso o min e o max sejam equivalentes.

Qualquer dúvida, se você usa eclipse, vá na opção `generate hashcode & equals`. Vale a pena colocar um `breakpoint` nestes métodos para ver como ele se comporta.

Segue a minha ideia de solução, existe outras abordagens de otimização de busca, procurei não quebrar muito a compatibilidade do teu código. Qualquer coisa dá um toque.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class BuscaGrafica {

Map<Integer, Region_> regionsHash = new HashMap<>();

void addRegion(Region_ region) {
    /**
     * Internamente ele vai guardar na posição de memória referente ao region.hashCode()
     * XXX Tem que ter atenção com este método, pois utilizando o hashCode como chave significa
     * que os elementos não poderão ser alterados, pois uma vez que eu alterar fará com
     * que o hashcode não seja mais o mesmo e o elemento de perca na memória.
     */
    regionsHash.put(region.hashCode(), region);
}

Region_ getRegion(vector _vector3D) {
    Region_ r = new Region_(_vector3D, _vector3D);
    // Otimização para procurar uma posição onde o minPos e maxPos sejam equivalentes
    if (regionsHash.containsKey(r)) {
        // A busca é instantânea não gera muito custo computacional
        regionsHash.get(r);
    } else {
        /**
         * Aqui não tem muito milagre, o cara vai ter que procurar na mão
         * Sugestões para aprimoramento desta rotina, poderá ser utilizado uma estrutura de dados
         * onde a ordenação dos elementos seja por ordem de grandeza
         * sendo assim podemos utilizar um algoritmo inteligente, que não precise percorrer todos os elementos do array.
         * Ficar atendo que o retorno pode ser mais de um {@link Region_}, pois pode haver mais de um elemento 3d dentro de outro ainda maior.
         */
        Map<Integer, Region_> collect = regionsHash.entrySet().stream()//
                .filter(element -> (element.getValue().maxPos.X >= _vector3D.X && element.getValue().maxPos.Y >= _vector3D.Y && element.getValue().maxPos.Z >= _vector3D.Z) && //
                                   (element.getValue().minPos.X <= _vector3D.X && element.getValue().minPos.Y <= _vector3D.Y && element.getValue().minPos.Z <= _vector3D.Z))//
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(p -> p.getKey(), p -> p.getValue()));
        // XXX aqui eu retornei o primeiro registro encontrado pelo lambda, mas é bom ficar atendo que o retorno pode ser mais de um...
        return collect.values().iterator().next();
    }
    return null;
}

public class Region_ {

    public Region_(vector _minPos, vector _maxPos) {
        minPos = _minPos;
        maxPos = _maxPos;
    }

    vector minPos;
    vector maxPos;

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + getOuterType().hashCode();
        result = prime * result + ((maxPos == null) ? 0 : maxPos.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((minPos == null) ? 0 : minPos.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) return true;
        if (obj == null) return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) return false;
        Region_ other = (Region_) obj;
        if (!getOuterType().equals(other.getOuterType())) return false;
        if (maxPos == null) {
            if (other.maxPos != null) return false;
        } else if (!maxPos.equals(other.maxPos)) return false;
        if (minPos == null) {
            if (other.minPos != null) return false;
        } else if (!minPos.equals(other.minPos)) return false;
        return true;
    }

    private BuscaGrafica getOuterType() {
        return BuscaGrafica.this;
    }

}

class vector {

    vector(int _X, int _Y, int _Z) {
        X = _X;
        Y = _Y;
        Z = _Z;
    }

    int X, Y, Z;

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + getOuterType().hashCode();
        result = prime * result + X;
        result = prime * result + Y;
        result = prime * result + Z;
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) return true;
        if (obj == null) return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) return false;
        vector other = (vector) obj;
        if (!getOuterType().equals(other.getOuterType())) return false;
        if (X != other.X) return false;
        if (Y != other.Y) return false;
        if (Z != other.Z) return false;
        return true;
    }

    private BuscaGrafica getOuterType() {
        return BuscaGrafica.this;
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Bem vindo a comunidade stackoverlow em português. Faça um [tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) e conheça um pouco das regras e boas práticas. Faça pelo menos uma demonstração de como poderia ser implementado, para ficar uma fácil visualização da resposta.